# sys_sendto Linux systemcall implementation

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, sendto

I am trying to explore the implementation of the "sendto" socket function. I tried to find an implementation in Linux.

In Linux, sendto function corresponds to "sys_sendto" system call. When I tried to follow it, I only found one definition for it which is the following:

asmlinkage long sys_sendto (void) **attribute**((weak,alias("sys_ni_syscall"))

That's to say sys_sendto is nothing than an alias to sys_ni_syscall, which does nothing more than returning a value. That does not make sense, as far as I am concerned. Where to find sys_snedto implementation? Is it implemented by some Assembly code?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Linux implementation of `sendto` [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.7/net/socket.c#L1775). As you can see, it is essentially a wrapper around the more powerful `sendmsg`.

It looks like you were looking at the declaration (prototype) for the system call, not the implementation.

Comment: I have already seen this page. Code shows that another function "sock_sendmsg" is doing the job. However, when I  tried to get its implementation I got nothing concrete. What I want is to get to the bottom of sendto function. In other words how a buffer gets transferred and how parameters (address, port,...) are passed.

Comment: Well, `sock_sendmsg` is defined in the very same file. Just look at what *that* does. You'll see that it calls `__sock_sendmsg` which in turn calls `__sock_sendmsg_nosec`. And there you see that the call is dispatched depending on what kind of socket is involved.

Answer (score 1):

It’s in `net/socket.c`, [line 1747 of v3.10-rc7](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/socket.c?id=refs/tags/v3.10-rc7#n1747).

```
/*
 *  Send a datagram to a given address. We move the address into kernel
 *  space and check the user space data area is readable before invoking
 *  the protocol.
 */

SYSCALL_DEFINE6(sendto, int, fd, void __user *, buff, size_t, len,
        unsigned int, flags, struct sockaddr __user *, addr,
        int, addr_len)
{
    struct socket *sock;
    struct sockaddr_storage address;
...
```

The `SYSCALL_DEFINE6` macro is the macro for defining syscalls that take six arguments. It’s defined in `include/linux/syscalls.h`. It’s pretty complicated, so let’s start by looking at what happens in the no-argument version:

```
#define SYSCALL_DEFINE0(sname)                                  \
        SYSCALL_METADATA(_##sname, 0);                          \
        asmlinkage long sys_##sname(void)
```

A system call like `getuid()`, defined in `kernel/sys.c`, is coded like this:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(getuid)
{
    /* Only we change this so SMP safe */
    return from_kuid_munged(current_user_ns(), current_uid());
}
```

The macro expands out to

```
SYSCALL_METADATA(_##sname, 0);
asmlinkage long sys_getuid(void)
{
    /* Only we change this so SMP safe */
    return from_kuid_munged(current_user_ns(), current_uid());
}
```

Which is a straightforward definition of the function `sys_getuid`.

The metadata is optionally compiled into the kernel for tracing. See the source in `syscalls.h` for the details.